# How to check if a value in an array is present in other object and accordingly return a new object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, json

I have an array

```
const dataCheck = ["Rohit","Ravi"];
```

I have another array of object

```
 const userData = [
    { name: "Sagar" },
    { name: "Vishal" },
    { name: "Rohit" },
    { name: "Ravi" },
  ];
```

I want to check if any value in dataCheck is present in the userData and then return a new array with the below data

```
const newData = [
    { name: "Sagar" },
    { name: "Vishal" },
    { name: "Rohit", status: "present" },
    { name: "Ravi", status: "present" },
  ];
```

I tried to do something using loops but not getting the expected results

```js
const dataCheck = ["Rohit", "Ravi"];
const userData = [
  { name: "Sagar" },
  { name: "Vishal" },
  { name: "Rohit" },
  { name: "Ravi" }
];

let newDataValue = {};
let newData = [];
userData.forEach((user) => {
  const name = user.name;
  dataCheck.forEach((userName) => {
    if (name === userName) {
      newDataValue = {
        name: name,
        status: "present"
      };
    } else {
      newDataValue = {
        name: name
      };
    }

    newData.push(newDataValue);
  });
});

console.log(newData);
```

My trial gives me repeated results multiple results which is just duplicates

Comment: Please try this one-line: `console.log(userData.map(({ name }) => (dataCheck.includes(name) ? { name, status: 'present' } : { name })));` and share your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
const dataCheck = ["Rohit","Ravi"];

const userData = [
  { name: "Sagar" },
  { name: "Vishal" },
  { name: "Rohit" },
  { name: "Ravi" },
];

const set = new Set(dataCheck);
const output = userData.map(data => set.has(data.name) ? ({...data, status: "present"}): data)
console.log(output)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A `Set` allows for lookups in `O(1)` time and therefore this algorithm works in `O(n)` time. If you would use the array for lookups (e.g. using `indcludes()`, `find()` etc.) the runtime would be `O(n²)`. Although this will certainly not matter at all for such small arrays, it will become more relevant the larger the array gets.

`map()` is used here because you want a `1:1` mapping of inputs to outputs. The only thing to determine then is, what the output should be. It is either the input, if the value is not in the `Set`, or it is the input extended by one property `status` set to `"present"`. You can check for the presence in a `Set` using the [`has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) method and can use the [`ternary operator ?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to make the decision which case it is.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through `userData`, check if name is includes in `dataCheck`. If `true` add status 'present'.

```js
const dataCheck = ["Rohit","Ravi"];

const userData = [
  { name: "Sagar" },
  { name: "Vishal" },
  { name: "Rohit" },
  { name: "Ravi" },
];

for (let user of userData) {
  if(dataCheck.includes(user.name)) {
    user.status = 'present'
  }
}

console.log(userData)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dataCheck = ["Rohit", "Ravi"];

const userData = [
  { name: "Sagar" },
  { name: "Vishal" },
  { name: "Rohit" },
  { name: "Ravi" },
];

// map through every object and check if name property
// exists in data check with help of filter. 
// if it exists the length of filter should be 1 so 
// you should return { name: el.name, status: "present" } else 
// return { name: el.name }

let newData = userData.map((el) => {
  if (dataCheck.filter((name) => name === el.name).length > 0) {
    return { name: el.name, status: "present" };
  } else {
    return { name: el.name };
  }
});

console.log("newdata: ", newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use `map` over `userData` array, find for matching element in `dataCheck`, if found return matching element + a status key or just return the found element as it is.

```
const dataCheck = ["Rohit","Ravi"];

const userData = [
    { name: "Sagar" },
    { name: "Vishal" },
    { name: "Rohit" },
    { name: "Ravi" },
];

const getUpdatedObject = () => {
  return userData.map(userData => {
    const userDetail = dataCheck.find(data => userData.name === data);
    if(userDetail) return {userDetail, status:"present"}
    else return {...userData}
   });
}

console.log(getUpdatedObject())
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sq0x8kLa/32/)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing repeated results due to the second loop `dataCheck.forEach((userName) => {` as every loop of `dataCheck` will fire the if/else statement and add something to the final array. However many values you add to `dataCheck` will be however many duplicates you get.

Only need to loop through one array and check if the value is in the other array so no duplicates get added.

```
const dataCheck = ["Rohit", "Ravi"];
const userData = [{ name: "Sagar" }, { name: "Vishal" }, { name: "Rohit" }, { name: "Ravi" }];

let newDataValue = {};
let newData = [];

// loop thru the users
userData.forEach((user) => {
    // set the user
    const name = user.name;

    // check if in array
    if (dataCheck.indexOf(name) >= 0) {
        newDataValue = {
            name: name,
            status: "present",
        };
    }
    // not in array
    else {
        newDataValue = {
            name: name,
        };
    }

    newData.push(newDataValue);
});

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you will do like this :

```
const dataCheck = ["Rohit","Ravi"];
const userData = [
    { name: "Sagar" },
    { name: "Vishal" },
    { name: "Rohit" },
    { name: "Ravi" },
];
const newUserData = userData.map( user => { 
     dataCheck.forEach( data => { 
          if( data === user.name ) 
             user.status = "present";
     }); 
     return user;

} );
console.log( newUserData );
```